# c# identifier expected in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When i type this in my controller page I am getting the error message "Identifier expected" after "loginViewModel". Any idea on how to fix this?

```
public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel, string Email, string Password)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Have you read [ask] and tried to search the web for that error? It means that you forgot to give your parameter a name, i.e. an identifier, you only specified its type.

Answer (score 3):

You declared a parameter type but didn't give it a name, this is the problem.

```
public IActionResult Login(LoginViewModel viewModel, string Email, string Password)
{
    return View();
}
```